# How to work generic with ranges?

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, range, protocols

My intention is the following:

My first function:

```
public func substringsOfLength(_ length: Int, inRange range: CountableClosedRange) -> Array<String>
{
    ...
}
```

And my second:

```
public func substringsOfLength(_ length: Int, inRange range: CountableRange) -> Array<String>
{
    ...
}
```

How can I realize both of them in one function? I know that Ranges are structures, so I can't use generalization paradigm. And I know too, that CountableRanges conform to RandomAccessCollection protocol and the bounds of them to Comparable, _Strideable and SignedInteger (Bound.Stride). Consequently, I search for a generic solution, right?

So I tried something like that:

```
public func substringsOfLength<T: RandomAccessCollection>(_ length: Int, inRange range: T) -> Array<String>
{
    ...
}
```

I know that here are the other protocols missing, but I don't know how to concretize the bounds with them.

Comment: What operations do you need on the range? They are both `Strideable`. Wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: When working with strings then  `Range<String.Index>` would be the natural type in Swift 3.

Comment: @Sulthan I just need access to the lower and the upper bound.

Comment: And if you want to work with integer ranges then you can simply use `Range<Int>`

Comment: @MartinR But then I can't use ClosedRanges.

Comment: But you can call it with `CountableRange(someClosedRange)`, which creates an equivalent half-open closed range.

Comment: Your first method can forward the call to the second method with `return substringsOfLength(length, inRange: CountableRange(range))`

Comment: @MartinR Although that won't work for `Range<String.Index>`, because `String.Index` isn't strideable.

Comment: Yes, for sure, but I want that this is possible: `substringsOfLength(length, inRange: 1 ... 2)` and this: `substringsOfLength(length, inRange: 1 ..< 2)` at the same time.

Comment: In Swift 4, you would want to use the `RangeExpression` protocol, to which all range types conform.

Comment: @Hamish: Yes, but it would work for `CountableClosedRange<Int>` which (I assume) OP is thinking about.

Comment: @MartinR If I use CountableClosedRange<Int> then I get the error `Cannot convert value of type 'CountableRange<Int>' to expected argument type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>'`, if I write `..<`.

Comment: @RainerNiemann: What I meant that you still write 2 methods, but one forwards the call to the other, so that the actual implementation is only in one method. There may be better solutions (in particular in Swift 4).

Comment: @MartinR Oh right, yes sorry I only just noticed that use of the countable variety of ranges in the question. But really, as you say, OP's method *ought* to be dealing with `String.Index` indices rather than `Int` offsets.

Comment: @MartinR: Ah okay, I now understand. But there is no other solution with generics?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, RandomAccessCollection is the "lowest" common protocol (and you can use `range.first!` / `range.last!` to get the bounds). But then the function could be called with *any* RandomAccessCollection, e.g. `inRange: [1, 4, 7]`. – As @Hamish said, RangeExpression can be used in Swift 4. – But again, `Range<String.Index>` would be the "natural" type, to avoid unnecessary index conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I will try a little bit different and more "Swifty" approach ...

```
import Foundation

let str = "1234 567 890 1 23456"

extension String {
    subscript(bounds: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
        get {
            return self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.lowerBound)...self.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.upperBound)]
        }
    }
    subscript(bounds: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
        get {
            return self[bounds.lowerBound...bounds.upperBound]
        }
    }
    var count: Int {
        get {
            return self.characters.count
        }
    }

    func substrings(separatedBy: CharacterSet, isIncluded: (String) -> Bool)->[String] {
        return self.components(separatedBy: separatedBy).filter(isIncluded)
    }
}



let a0 = str[2..<14].components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).filter {
    $0.count == 3
}
let a1 = str[2...13].substrings(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
    $0.count == 3
}
```

prints

```
["567", "890"] ["567", "890"]
```

Very soon the String will be the collection of characters and life will be easier ... (then just remove a part of your code)

As you can see, the function substrings is almost redundant and probably is better to remove it.